# Make Moq output invocation of all methods to console

Tags: c#, moq

How can I configure Moq in a way to output every method invocation (invoked method name and parameters) to console without writing this yourself for each method? I am trying to have these method invocations in order of execution output to a log file without doing this manually for every method. Alternatively, it would be fine to have this behavior for all methods centralized in the test setup method in such a way that a subsequent call to "Setup" (from a test method) of a mocked class would not overwrite the already set up logging logic.

Checking the Invocations property at the end of the test is not an option, since there might be several other mocked classes and I would not know the exact order of execution.

How can I achieve this behavior in Moq?

Here is an example:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetupTest()
{
    _encryptionServiceMock = new Mock<IEncryptionService>();
    _secretRepositoryMock = new Mock<ISecretRepository>();
    
    // arrange mocks to output all method invocations to console
}

[Test]
public void SomeTestCase()
{
    // arrange
    _secretRepositoryMock.Setup(sr => sr.GetById(1)).Returns("abcdefg");
    _secretRepositoryMock.Setup(sr => sr.GetById(2)).Returns("hijklmn");
    _encryptionServiceMock.Setup(sr => sr.Decrypt("abcdefg", "encryption key")).Returns("first decrypted secret");
    _encryptionServiceMock.Setup(sr => sr.Decrypt("hijklmn", "encryption key")).Returns("second decrypted secret");
    
    // arrange (this gets called at some point in the test)
    var encryptedSecretOne = _secretRepositoryMock.Object.GetById(1);
    var decryptedSecretOne = _encryptionServiceMock.Object.Decrypt(encryptedSecretOne, "encryption key");

    var encryptedSecretTwo = _secretRepositoryMock.Object.GetById(2);
    var decryptedSecretTwo = _encryptionServiceMock.Object.Decrypt(encryptedSecretTwo, "encryption key");
    
    // act
    
    // assert
            
    // Expected output:
    //
    // secretRepositoryMock     GetById(1) returned "abcdefg"
    // encryptionServiceMock    Decrypt("abcdefg", "encryption key") returned "first decrypted secret"
    // secretRepositoryMock     GetById(2) returned "hijklmn"
    // encryptionServiceMock    Decrypt("hijklmn", "encryption key") returned "second decrypted secret"
}
```

Comment: Please share with some code which shows how did you try to tackle your problem. Or at least share with a sample unit test and the expected invocation list.

Comment: I have added an example. I currently do not see a way how to do this other than writing some custom extension method "ReturnsWithLogging" which takes a Func as input, uses reflection to log the parameters and then invokes the Func and outputs the result to Console. But by doing this, I am losing the option to setup a simple Return which returns a value without a Func. "Setup(...).Returns(true)" would need to become "Setup(...).ReturnsWithLogging((string arg1) => true);"

Comment: How about accessing the invocation parameters via the mock objects, like: `_secretRepositoryMock.Invocations[0].Arguments[0] as int`?

Comment: That doesn't work, since I need this in order of execution where several mocks might be involved. Another drawback is that I couldn't combine this with other logging from a test.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing my own extensions of Moq (extension method "SetupWithLogging").

Usage:

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ISomeService>();
    mock.SetupWithLogging(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns<string>(false);
    mock.Object.DoSomething("ha");
}

public interface ISomeService
{
    bool DoSomething(string a);
}
```

Custom extensions:

```
public static class MockExtensions
{
    public static ICustomSetup<TResult> SetupWithLogging<T, TResult>(this Mock<T> mock, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression) where T : class
    {
        string methodName = ((MethodCallExpression)expression.Body).Method.Name;

        return new CustomSetupParameters<T, TResult>(methodName, mock.Setup(expression));
    }
}

public interface ICustomSetup<in TResult>
{
    void Returns<TInput>(TResult result);
}

internal class CustomSetupParameters<T, TResult> : ICustomSetup<TResult> where T : class
{
    private readonly string _methodName;
    private readonly ISetup<T, TResult> _mock;

    internal CustomSetupParameters(string methodName, ISetup<T, TResult> mock)
    {
        _methodName = methodName;
        _mock = mock;
    }

    public void Returns<TInput1>(TResult result)
    {
        _mock.Returns<TInput1>((a) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{_methodName}({a}): {result}");

            return result;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Super cool. Not quite what I need to do but I'll keep it in mind. Thanks for sharing!